# How to inject WorkManager instance in a ViewModel constructor with Dagger2?

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-2, dagger, android-workmanager

I want inject a WorkManager instance with Dagger2 to use it in my ViewModel like this

```
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(workManager: WorkManager) : ViewModel()
```

When I try to create a Module for WorkManager to provide an instance of it I getting an error that says, I can't provide from an abstract class. How can inject an instance of WorkManager in my ViewModel constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an instance of `WorkManager` without Dagger, you would use [`WorkManager.getInstance(context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getInstance(android.content.Context)).  To put `WorkManager` in the object graph in Dagger, we simply need to put this code in a `@Provides` method.

```
@Provides
// Maybe @Singleton, though it really doesn't matter.
fun provideWorkManager(context: Context): WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
```

With this method in a Dagger module, you will be able to inject `WorkManager` anywhere, provided your component has access to a `Context`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much @Nitrodon

Comment: Correct Way: @ApplicationContext appContext: Context

Answer (score 5):

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object YourModule {    
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideWorkManager(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): WorkManager =
        WorkManager.getInstance(appContext)
}
```

Inject to ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class YourViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val workManager: WorkManager
) : ViewModel() {
```